# How to adjust table row height when using font-awesome icon in bootstrap 4?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Whenever I add font-awesome icon on my table my table row height increases. I am using bootstrap 4 and font-awesome 4.7.0

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-stripped">
    <thead>
        <th></th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Featured</th>
        <th>Sold</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <!-- Here is the problem-->
            <td><i class="fa fa-edit" style="font-size:30px;color:red"></i></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When Use font-awesome in bootstrap 4

**See icon is small here when I increase icon size my row height also increases**

[image]

**I want this icon size and row height is perfect**

[image]

when I use font-awesome icon then my table row height increase and when I remove `class="fa fa-edit"` then my table look ok and table row height get short. I want to adjust font-awesome icon and my table row height but I am unable to do it.

For solving this problem I add `style="font-size:30px"` in `<i>` then my font icon visible properly on my table row but table row height increases which look odd. I want to increase `font-size` of my icon but do not want to increase my table row height or I also want to adjust my table row height manually. For this I have used `<td height="100">` but it did not work.
`<tr height="100">` but it did not work with font-awesome icon.

Your valuable suggestions would be a great help for a beginner like me.
Thank You.

Comment: can you show more of your code? i unable to replicate the issue you are concern with

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

Comment: <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-stripped">
     <thead>
      <th></th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Featured</th>
      <th>Sold</th>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <tr>
     <!-- Here is the problem-->
       <td><i class="fa fa-edit" style="font-size:30px;color:red"></i></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>




</body>
</html>

Comment: I have tried <td class="container"> <style> td.container > div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
td.container {
    height: 20px;
}
</style> but it also did not work with font-awesome icon. In bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `.table-condensed` is gone for `Bootstrap 4`. Use `.table-sm` instead.

Secondly, there is only little room to adjust before the icons get so big that they increase the row height. You can remove the cell's padding `.3rem` by `.table-sm` but that's the only thing you can do.

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/uj1p9owa/

What's wrong with the default font size? I think it looks cool.

[image]